# How can I create a stack view like tinder in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uicollectionview

[image]

I want to create a stacked view like this in ios using swift. Is it possible to achieve this by using uicollectionview or something? can someone point me in the right direction?

What I essentially want is something similar to how tinder works.
(Yes I have seen libraries for this but I want something simple and not using existing solutions)

Comment: There is no in-built control in iOS for this kind of view, so you will either need to use some library or write your own code (not simple)

Comment: try this out https://www.github.com/nickypatson/TinderSwipeView

Answer (score 5):

You're in luck! There's a great library you can use called **Koloda**. It's written in Swift and I've had success integrating it on a prior project. The devs are also responsive and it has a decent size community around it on GitHub. Good luck:
https://github.com/Yalantis/Koloda

Comment: How does this work in terms of license and rights? I am using this in a commercial app.

Comment: You know you could've just clicked the LICENSE file. It's MIT licensed. If you don't know what that is, you should Google it. But basically you can use it wherever you want, however you want as long as you give credit to its author somewhere in your app. https://github.com/Yalantis/Koloda/blob/master/LICENSE

Answer (score 4):

If you want to implement this by yourself than you can use the following approach:

- create draggable UIView-descendant class (for this you have to add gesturerecognizer as a property and write some animations including dissapearance of this object from superview). it is your card (draggableview.swift).
- create an array with several cards (2, for example — card 0 and card 1) in your viewcontroller; set delegates for each card
- create delegate methods in your viewcontroller (the logic is like that: you already able to remove the top card — card 0 — from superview but after that you need to add the new card to the array and put this card below the card 1; now card 1 is the top one, et cetera).

it's not very complicated actually.